# Is it appropriate to ask HR for a time frame for the response about application when I know hiring manager has made a decision?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, human-resources, applications

I made it to the last round of interviews for a job, and, as far as I can tell, things went well. Right after the last interview the hiring manager and the team leader were fairly open and told me I made a very good impression but asked me to wait 3 to 4 weeks for their response as there was still another candidate they wanted to interview.

After the fourth week had past and I hadn't heard from them I wrote an email to the manager asking if they knew when they would be making their decision. In his response he told me that they had already made a decision and that HR would get in touch with me. The response was friendly and he implied that I should be expecting good news. (for me and a friend it's the most likely interpretation by the way he worded it)

A week has past and I haven't heard from HR. This position is in the headquarters of a huge company with over 100k employees worldwide so I understand that processes could be slower, but I am growing anxious because 1. I have kept another company waiting for my response and 2. I'm nearing a deadline for an important decision in my current job that would be affected if I knew 100% for sure if I was leaving.

I feel tempted to write an email to the person from HR who I met in the first interview and ask them about a time frame in which I should be expecting the outcome of their decision. However, I don't want to risk making a wrong move since this would be a great career opportunity for me and it's something I've been working for for so long.
I wouldn't make mention of my interaction with the manager.

Is it appropriate in this situation to write an email to HR asking about a time frame in which they would get in touch with me about their decision?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the Workplace -- I have linked to a possible duplicate. It's also possible that they made a decision and selected another candidate. Either way, you don't really gain anything from contacting the company.

Comment: I actually don't think this is a duplicate, because in this case, you have decisions you need to make that are blocked as you wait to learn about this job.  I would send one more email to the hiring manager, letting him know that you are very interested in this role, but that you will be forced to accept another offer in one week's time (or whatever, be truthful).  If they intended to make you an offer, this will get them moving; if you hear nothing, well, then you know the answer.

Comment: @dan.mwasuser2321368 I see what you mean -- I think you are correct that this is different.

Comment: Actually I would not just ask for timing but let them know that you have other opportunities on hold. Tell them that they are your first choice, but you need a decision relatively soon. If you didn't get the job, you've nothing to lose. If you are the lead candidate, than this can be an effective way of convince an overly sluggish HR department to get their rear into gear.